# jquery autcomplete not working when i use .ajaxstop for other function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

i use this js to show a "please wait" popup for all pages of  my web "i include it in header"
and its working fine and show the pop up with every ajax call and hide after it finish in.

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {$('#loadingDiv').dialog({ resizable: false }).show();$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();})
    .ajaxStop(function() {$('#loadingDiv').dialog("close");});
```

problem occur in pages that use jquery autocomplete plugin as it interfere with autocomplete and ac does not show its dropdown list anymore
My autocomplete JS

```
$('input.completeme').each(function() {


$(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>booking/ac',
                data: { 'term': this.term,'name': this.element.attr('name') },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui){
                    $("#pt_name").val(ui.item.name);
                    $("#pt_id").val(ui.item.id);
                    $("#pt_dob").val(ui.item.dob);
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

i think because autocomplete also use .ajaxStop, so is there way to fix this?

i really like this function because it bind to all ajax call and i includ it in my header and not worry about plz wait popup anymore. but it looks like autocomplete hate it :(

Answer (score 0):

Use "document" to bind ajaxStop event.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){...})
```

I have tested this solution & there was no problem.